# issue while retrieving the images from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve five images from a database and display those in single row.  My code is retrieving all the images' data but not the image itself. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        include "config.php";


        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register r
                          JOIN videos v ON r.id = v.video_id
                          ORDER BY r.id desc LIMIT 5") or die (mysql_error());

        $headers = $col = "";
        $row=mysql_num_rows($q);
        $s=null;

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) 
        {
        if($row['id']!=$s)
        {
        $s = $row['id'];


        echo "<div class='property'>";
        echo "<div class='property1' >";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src='".$row['path']."' height='100' width='170' style= margin:5px;></a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='property2'>";
        echo $row['videoname'];
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='property3'>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "by:";
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='property4'>";
        echo $row['views'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;views&nbsp;';
        echo $row['time'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;year ago';
        echo "</div>";


        echo "</div>";

        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: What does `$row['path']` give? `var_dump($row['path'])`. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5, use mysqi or PDO instead.

Comment: Do you have a HTML output for it? In $row['path'] I assume you have full PATH+Filename.extension right?

Comment: no in database i saved it as in text format. while inserting it is going one folder which i have crested at the same i'm going to save the path to the database in text format.. in database it s save like photos/1.jpg,photos/2.jpg

Comment: @user3422452 When fetching the image, is the path it's referencing to correct? *photos/1.jpg* could be incorrect as it's a relative path.

Comment: On your browser `right click` inspect element over the `property1` class and see what you got?

Comment: @Richard i.m going to retrive the image by using the path

Comment: @Rangith i'm getting image size and width not the image its showing image watermark

Comment: @user3422452 : Not getting correctly. please copy and paste in comments or question.

Comment: see what i'm trying is have to retrieve the images from database, ehat are all the information i have given i can able retrive the data regarding images, for image i have given width & height the width & height of the image i'm getting not the exact image.. please reply

Comment: @user3422452 I am trying to say you, update the `img tag`. For example, `<img src="your-path" height='100' width='170' style= margin:5px;>`